# How do I write a valid CIF, PDB or XYZ file from the coordinates listed below?

Tags: crystal-structure, software, cheminformatics

I want to create a 3D molecular file using coordinates taken from:

- Hrynchuk, RJ; Barton, RJ; Robertson, BE (1983). "[The crystal structure of free base cocaine, C17H21NO4](http://www.nrcresearchpress.com/doi/pdf/10.1139/v83-085)" (PDF). *Canadian Journal of Chemistry* **61** (3): 481–487. doi:[10.1139/v83-085](http://dx.doi.org/10.1139/v83-085).

Here are the coordinates:

```
              X             Y            Z
C(1)          0.5419        0.1631       0.7095
C(2)          0.4579        0.2047       0.5345
C(3)          0.3080        0.1713       0.5168
C(4)          0.2903        0.0286       0.5727
C(5)          0.3950        0.0004       0.7409
C(6)          0.3870        0.1080       0.8678
C(7)          0.4858        0.2192       0.8450
C(8)          0.1028        0.2512       0.3219
C(9)          0.0323        0.2713       0.1411
C(10)         0.0857        0.2213       0.0238
C(11)         0.0189        0.2435       -0.1419
C(12)        -0.0995        0.3166        -0.1875
C(13)        -0.1528        0.3671      -0.0719
C(14)        -0.0880        0.3462      0.0951
C(15)         0.5172        0.1331      0.4127
C(16)         0.7261        0.1009      0.3465
C(17)         0.6418        -0.0439     0.8543

N(1)          0.5324        0.0158      0.7182

O(1)          0.2257        0.1933      0.3470
O(2)          0.0560        0.2836      0.4306
O(3)          0.4616        0.0531      0.3097
O(4)          0.6481        0.1713      0.4393

H(1)          0.6210        0.1840      0.7230
H(2)          0.4640        0.2980      0.5170
H(3)          0.2820        0.2340      0.5830
H(4)          0.1930        0.0110      0.5730
H(5)          0.3050        -0.0240     0.4930
H(6)          0.3850        -0.0960     0.7770
H(7)          0.4090        0.0810      0.9760
H(8)          0.2870        0.1410      0.8610
H(9)          0.4440        0.3140      0.8150
H(10)         0.5560        0.2330      0.9400
H(11)         0.1580        0.1680      0.0530
H(12)         0.0640        0.2050      -0.2240
H(13)         -0.1470        0.3330      -0.3060
H(14)         -0.2320        0.4140      -0.103
H(15)         -0.1280        0.3810      0.186
H(16)         0.7330        0.0190      0.3810
H(17)         0.8130        0.1470      0.3710
H(18)         0.6990        0.1060      0.2370
H(19)         0.7250        -0.0340      0.836
H(20)         0.6470        -0.0070      0.961
H(21)         0.6230        -0.1410      0.861
```

Converting this to XYZ coordinates, namely to:

```
43
Cocaine 1983
C          0.5419        0.1631       0.7095
C          0.4579        0.2047       0.5345
C          0.3080        0.1713       0.5168
C          0.2903        0.0286       0.5727
C          0.3950        0.0004       0.7409
C          0.3870        0.1080       0.8678
C          0.4858        0.2192       0.8450
C          0.1028        0.2512       0.3219
C          0.0323        0.2713       0.1411
C          0.0857        0.2213       0.0238
C          0.0189        0.2435       -0.1419
C         -0.0995        0.3166        -0.1875
C         -0.1528        0.3671      -0.0719
C         -0.0880        0.3462      0.0951
C          0.5172        0.1331      0.4127
C          0.7261        0.1009      0.3465
C          0.6418        -0.0439     0.8543
N          0.5324        0.0158      0.7182
O          0.2257        0.1933      0.3470
O          0.0560        0.2836      0.4306
O          0.4616        0.0531      0.3097
O          0.6481        0.1713      0.4393
H          0.6210        0.1840      0.7230
H          0.4640        0.2980      0.5170
H          0.2820        0.2340      0.5830
H          0.1930        0.0110      0.5730
H          0.3050        -0.0240     0.4930
H          0.3850        -0.0960     0.7770
H          0.4090        0.0810      0.9760
H          0.2870        0.1410      0.8610
H          0.4440        0.3140      0.8150
H          0.5560        0.2330      0.9400
H          0.1580        0.1680      0.0530
H          0.0640        0.2050      -0.2240
H          -0.1470        0.3330      -0.3060
H          -0.2320        0.4140      -0.103
H          -0.1280        0.3810      0.186
H          0.7330        0.0190      0.3810
H          0.8130        0.1470      0.3710
H          0.6990        0.1060      0.2370
H          0.7250        -0.0340      0.836
H          0.6470        -0.0070      0.961
H          0.6230        -0.1410      0.861
```

Opening this with Accelrys gives this structure. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijb19.png

Comment: @AbelFriedman It is not cartesian coordinates. While xyz file is quite easy to construct, I can't guess an easy method to convert them, so it seems more convenient to find structure of compound of interest in more suitable form.

Comment: @permeakra: Wikipedia has the transformation matrix for [fractional coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_coordinates) to cartesian coordinates.  The crystal system is monoclinic, which makes the transformation rather painless, nothing that a few lines of awk won't do.

Comment: Although its now old rasmol and rasmac is very relaxed about exact format as long as the atom type appear after the coordinates.  Its also free, and very fast to use if you need to rotate large protein models. It will do most simple angle and distance calculations etc. Basic, but very useful for quick look stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, `babel` from the [Openbabel suite](http://openbabel.org) will convert chemical file formats.  The openbabel wiki has a [page](http://openbabel.org/wiki/Free_Form_Fractional) with examples on input in free-form fractional coordinate format, and the abstract of the paper has the unit cell dimensions.

Single CIF files can be requested from the [Cambridge Crystallographic Data Centre](http://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/pages/Home.aspx).

Comment: +1 Indeed, this would be my exact answer. It's the reason I added "free form fractional" to babel, since you run across this problem in older papers.

Comment: I have a first year chem knowledge, so at the moment I haven't the foggiest as to what "free-form fractional coordinate format" means. I made that request but they don't have such a CIF file at this data centre.

Comment: @BrentonHorne: It's an oblique coordinate system formed by the unit cell of the crystal.  The angles between the axes are the angles of the unit cell, and the units are dimensionless and expressed in terms of the edges of the unit cell.

Comment: OK, how do I do that for my example? I have no idea what to set the unit cell as.

Comment: @BrentonHorne: Look no further than the abstract for unit cell parameters: a, b, c, \beta. \alpha == \gamma == 90 deg, since the crystal system is monoclinic.